# Fail when i use Bridging Headers in swift frameworks

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

I am doing a swift framework and i want to use old objective c classes. For this, i use the bridging headers method but when i try to build appears this error:

```
<unknown>:0: error: using bridging headers with framework targets is unsupported
```

I added my {PROJECT}-Bridging-Header.h to Objective-C Bridging Header in Swift Compiler - Code Generation

How can i solved it?

I did in applications and runs Ok, but in this framework no

Thanks

Comment: yeah, but is true? you can mix swift and objective-c in apps but not in frameworks?

Comment: Sorry for being a smart-ass. You use the framework umbrella header instead of a bridging header when building a framework: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_82

Comment: and how can i create umbrella header? whats is the difference=

Comment: It will be a `.h` file with the same name as your framework containing the version number and version string. Look for `FOUNDATION_EXPORT double {framework name}`.

Answer (score 2):

iHart is correct

For that follow below steps :
1. remove your bridging header and all related file . . .
2. Clean Build/Solution. Cmd + Shift + k like . . .
3. Create new Objective-C file for bridging header file creation . . .

But what I had to do also is add all the missing header files to my umbrella header. And also make sure that these files are marked public.  In Xcode you can add them to the public section under Build Phases -> Header.

Answer (score -1):

For that follow below steps:

1. Remove your bridging header and all related file.
2. Clean Build. Cmd + Shift + k like.
3. Create new Objective-C file for bridging header file creation.
4. Now, add your others file.

I hope, this work for you because we solved exactly the same error this solution.